# How to unit test a httprequest using corouties

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to do some unit tests and mock a fake `httpresponse`.
I've created an `httprequest`

But when i do `"whenever(repository.search(any())).thenReturn(response)"`, I've got a "`NullPointerException` on `"search()"`

When I run the app on device / emulator, it's working well

```
@Test
fun searchUser_success() {
    val expectedUser = User("Louis", 1, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 0.0)
    val result = Result(1, false, listOf(expectedUser))
    val response = RTResponse.Success(result)
    whenever(runBlocking { repository.search("Louis") }).thenReturn(response)
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedUser, viewModel.users.value)
}

class SearchRepository(private val searchInterface: SearchInterface) {
    suspend fun search(user: String): RTResponse<Result> {
        val response = searchInterface.searchAsync(query = user, page = 1, perPage = 10).await()
        return try {
            if (response.isSuccessful) RTResponse.Success(response.body()!!) else RTResponse.Error(IOException(""))
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            RTResponse.Error(IOException("Unable to fetch users"))
        }
    }
}


interface SearchInterface {
    //http request
    @GET("search/users")
    fun searchAsync(@Query("q") query: String,
                    @Query("page") page: Int,
                    @Query("per_page") perPage: Int): Deferred<Response<Result>>

    //singleton instance of Retrofit
    companion object Factory { /* build retrofit instance */ }
}
```

Comment: Could you please also provide code for `RTResponse`, `Response`, `Result`, `User`, `viewModel` and whole code for test class. Also a stacktrace of Exception would be useful.